# Batch rename screen shots on Mac OS X

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Custom batch rename files

Hello, Mac OS X takes screen shot's in a very long format of filename.  I would like to rename any of them that sit at path /Users/me/desktop.

Here are some examples of the filenames:

```
Screen Shot 2012-08-02 at 1.15.29 AM.png
Screen Shot 2012-08-02 at 1.22.12 AM.png
Screen Shot 2012-08-02 at 1.22.14 PM.png
Screen Shot 2012-08-02 at 1.22.16 PM.png
```

I was once told, not to do a for loop against an `ls` so I am trying globbing this time around.  So far, this is all I can come up with, but done know how to karen wrap the expression and then get that to a file rename in the format I desire:

```
 for i in *; do
      screen_name=$(echo $i | grep --only-matching --extended-regexp '(Screen\ Shot)\ [0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\ at\ [0-9]+\.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[AP]M\.png');
      echo $screen_name;
 done
```

I am not sure about the hour of the time, it may be safest to assume possible 2 digits on all chunks of the time, so 1.14.29 and 01.15.29

```
ss.08-02-12-01.15.29-AM.png
ss.08-02-12-01.22.12-AM.png
ss.08-02-12-01.22.14-PM.png
ss.08-02-12-01.22.16-PM.png
```

The end goal, is a bash script that when run will rename ALL files at the above mentioned path to the new format listed.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in "Screen Shot"*.png; do
    new=`echo $i |awk '
        {
            split($3,a,"-")
            split($5,b,".")
            printf("ss.%s-%s-%s-%02d.%02d.%02d-%s",a[2],a[3],a[1],b[1],b[2],b[3],$6)
        }
    '`
    mv "$i" $new
done
```

**Before:**

```
Screen Shot 2012-08-02 at 1.22.16 PM.png
Screen Shot 2012-09-02 at 13.42.06 PM.png
```

**After:**

```
ss.08-02-2012-01.22.16-PM.png
ss.09-02-2012-13.42.06-PM.png
```

**EDIT:**
as suggested by [steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751863/steve)

```
printf("ss.%s-%s-%s-%02d.%02d.%02d-%s",a[2],a[3],substr(a[1]3,2),b[1],b[2],b[3],$6)
```

which yields

```
ss.08-02-12-01.22.16-PM.png
ss.09-02-12-13.42.06-PM.png
```

Comment: +1 Exactly how I would have done it, but I may have used `awk -F "[-. ]+"` to avoid arrays

Comment: Will work fine. Ok, performance probably doesn't really matter here but I'd generally never use awk for what can easily be done with sed.

Comment: @inVader, I think `printf %02d` would be hard to replicate with `sed`

Comment: @steve - It could be done using assertions but I admit that it would make the expressions way more complex and difficult to read. I see your point there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream editor **sed** to match and substitute using regular expressions. You would do something like this

```
echo $i | sed "s/PATTERN/REPLACE/"
```

to genereate the filename out of $i. **sed** will read from stdin, search (**s** command) for pattern and replace it with REPLACE.

In your REGEXP pattern you can mark seperate groups by surrounding them with brackets **()**, in most situations you will have to escape them by **()** and access these parts in the replace pattern by using **#**, where # is the number of the subgroup starting from 1. Here's a simple example:

```
echo "ScreenShotXYZ.png" | sed "s/ScreenShot\(.*\)\.png/\1.png/"
```

Here, the XYZ is matched by the expression in brackets and can be accessed using \1 in the replacment string. The whole pattern in thus replaced by XYZ.png.

So use your regexp for matching, put brackets around the relevant blocks and do something like

```
ss.\1.\2.(and so on)
```

for your replacement pattern. There's still some way to optimize the process by first using sed to replace dashes by dots, then grouping the whole time block in just one pattern but for a start it's easier to code like that.

Comment: Thanks inVader, this got me on the right track and I was able to get it working with your hints, thank you again.  Here is how I ended up going at it, though I may adapt to the other method for some bits.  It was yours that got me on the right track.  http://pastebin.com/fUyy3AGf  Thanks!